# What's the difference between "associated" and "bound" roles in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm just about to get OpenShift up and running but there's one thing I cant really wrap my head around. What's the difference between being "associated" and "bound" to roles in OpenShift?

I know what roles and bindings are and how they work. But it seems to me, that associating rules is pretty much everything I can do. I can "give" a rule to a User. But what does it mean to "bind" someone to a rule?

Thanks in advance.

What I'm referring to: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/openshift-enterprise/version-3.0/openshift-enterprise-30-architecture#roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding is the verb we use to describe giving a user a role.  The API resource is called a RoleBinding.  Other words we use are "grant" or "assign".